# Retrieve most similar content and display as first result in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two files name (Text and Text1) in the database
Text.txt content include "data".
Text1.txt content include "data" and "data1".

[image]

SQL Query that I wrote:

```
SELECT [FileName], [FilePath] FROM dbo.[tb_CrawlData] cr  
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [tb_CrawlData] cd
              WHERE cd.Content like '%data%' AND
                    cr.Content like '%' + cd.Content + '%'
             )
    GROUP BY cr.FileName, [FilePath] 
    ORDER BY cr.FileName
```

Result:

```
FileName    FilePath
Text.txt    H:\Text.txt
Text1.txt   H:\New folder (2)\Text1.txt
```

Expected Result:

If I search "data", I would like to get Text1.txt first in my first row 
because it have two similar content ("data" and "data1").
    Text.txt should display second row because it contains only ("data").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `count(*) desc` in the `order by` clause:

```
select [FileName],
    [FilePath]
from dbo.[tb_CrawlData] cr
where exists (
        select 1
        from [tb_CrawlData] cd
        where cd.Content like '%data%'
            and cr.Content like '%' + cd.Content + '%'
        )
group by cr.FileName,
    [FilePath]
order by count(*) desc,
    cr.FileName
```

Comment: @GurV...thank you so much
That is exactly what I want.